# Weak Hopf algebra structure on twisted group algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, subfactors

A (normalized) $2$-cocycle on a finite group $G$ with values in $S^1$ is a map
$\sigma:G\times G\rightarrow S^1$ such that $$\sigma(g,h)\sigma(gh,k)=\sigma(h,k)\sigma(g,hk)$$ and $$\sigma(g,e)=\sigma(e,g)=1.$$ Let $\{\delta_g\}$ denote the canonical basis of $l^2(G)$. Define, $\lambda_{\sigma}(g)(\delta_h)=\sigma(g,h)\delta_{gh}.$ The twisted group von Neumann
algebra $L_{\sigma}(G)$ is the von Neumann subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(l^2(G))$ generated by $\lambda_{\sigma}(G).$ My question is the following:

$\textbf{Question:}$ Can one provide a natural weak Kac algebra structure on $L_{\sigma}(G)$?

Edit: Note that group $C^*$-algebra has a natural Kac algebra structure if we define $\Delta(g)=g\otimes g$, $\epsilon(g)=1$ and $S(g)=g^{-1}$. In my question I have used "natural" in this spirit. In other words, the formulae for comultiplication, antipode and counit should involve group and the cocycle.

For definition of weak Hopf (and Kac) algebra see:

[BNS] Böhm, Gabriella; Nill, Florian; Szlachányi, Kornel (1999). "Weak Hopf algebras. I. Integral theory and $C^*$-structure". Journal of Algebra. 221 (2): 385–438.

[NV] Dmitri Nikshych, Leonid Vainerman; Algebraic versions of a finite-dimensional quantum groupoid.

Comment: Probably not. Take $G = \Gamma \times \hat\Gamma$ for some finite Abelian grouo $\Gamma$ and the cocycle $(g, \chi) \mapsto \langle g, \chi\rangle$. Then, $L_\sigma(G) = L \Gamma \rtimes_{\alpha} \hat{\Gamma}$, where $\alpha$ is the dual action. That equals $M_{|\Gamma|}(\mathbb{C})$ by Sakai's duality, but i think there are no nontrivial comultiplication structures on matrices.

Comment: I think there is a natural comultiplication structure on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ given by matrix units which also makes it a coalgebra structure together with a counit given by $\epsilon(e_{ij})=\delta_{ij}$. However, since matrix algebra is simple this coalgebra structure is not compatible with the algebra structure of the matrices and hence it is not a bialgebra (and hence not a Hopf algebra). But, it is not clear to me why matrix algebra can not be made into a weak Hopf algbera. @AdriánGonzález-Pérez

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Why it should follow that $n=1$?

Comment: @Sebastein I think it is appropriate to keep "Can one provide" as explained in my first comment. I am doubtful about your guess.

Comment: My guess was false according to the paper of Nikshych and Vainerman cited above: « Then we show that for any f-d C*-algebra $A$ there exists a unique weak Kac algebra structure (non-trivial when $A$ is non-abelian) on the full matrix algebra $M_n(C)$ (where $n = dim A$) with Cartan subalgebras isomorphic to $A$. This gives a classification of weak Kac algebras simple as C*-algebras ».

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez: see Theorem 3.2.2 in the second paper cited above.

Comment: @ Sebastien Yes I have also realised that your guess can not be correct. In fact, as I have already indicated earlier that you can construct $\Delta, \epsilon $ and $S$ using matrix units and using these by hand one can easily show that matrix algebra has a natural weak Kac algebra structure.

Comment: What about defining a weak Kac algebra structure on any finite dimensional C*-algebra, component-wise, using what is known for $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I was not aware of that result, thanks for the reference. My first comment is invalid.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux Yes, this will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux But the information of co-cycle will be lost.